# How to set image to ImageView from ArrayList<String> in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an android application for image sharing.In mainactivity one gridview that shows images from `Arraylist<String>` named `img` .when i clicked on any image then another activity called that have only one ImageView that shows image that i select on mainactivity, but i am not able set image in ImageView using `ImageView.setImageResource(img.get(currentImage))` method.where `img` is `ArrayList` of string type.

any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Create `ArrayList` of `Drawable` and pass position to another `Activity` and load `Image` from `Drawable ArrayList` as per `position` ..

Comment: Need to convert your image to `Bitmap` and need to use `setImageBitmap`.

Comment: Try to pass selected image path to another activity using intent put extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an ArrayList of Integers and then easily assign the image to the imageview:

Example code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(R.drawable.your_image);
imageView.setImageResource(Integer.intValue(list.get(0)));
```

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(Integer.intValue(list.get(0)));

it give me error : Non-static method 'intvalue()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: it's intValue() and not intvalue(), try again :)

Answer (score 0):

Within the array will store the names of the pictures, like R.drawable.img1 , R.drawable.img2...
Then, use the command:

```
ImageView img;
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
```